# Simplest validation with JaXB

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb

I want to validate xml documents with JaXB.

Code :

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File("D:/liferay-develop/workspace/cat_test/v2/STD_MP.xsd")));
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

Now i want to get error if document not valide to schema. In examples is see that guys create EventHandler classes for this ( like this http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html). But maybe exist more simplest way to get validation error in conlose and in variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ValidationEventHandler` approach is how you get a handle on the validation events.  You could do something like the following if you are looking to minimize the amount of code you need to write:

```
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getMessage());
            return true;
        }

    });
```